# Como transformar uma lista em vetor no R?

Tags: r, lista

Como transformar uma lista em vetor no R? A lista é um conjunto de palavras e números e preciso somar os números presentes na lista.

```
mylist <- list ("2 tomates", "5 tomates", "9 tomates")
```

Se quero o total de tomates, como fazer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pelo menos duas maneiras -- com certeza há outras:

```
# note a diferenca entre as listas
mylist <- list ("2 tomates", "5 tomates", "9 tomates")
```

primero,

```
myvector <- unlist(mylist)
x = regmatches(myvector, regexpr("[0-9]+", myvector))
y = as.numeric(x)
sum(y)
```

ou então

```
numeros = function(x) {
  regmatches(x, regexpr("[0-9]+", x))[1]
}
x = unlist(lapply(mylist, numeros))
y = as.numeric(x)
sum(y)
```

Ambas as respostas assumem que a expressão regular `"[0-9]+"` é o que você quer.

Na minha resposta, assumi que `mylist` tinha 3 componentes, e não um como na pergunta original.